# Passing dynamic values on page redirect

Tags: redirect, dynamic, coldfusion, cfml

I have a GUI with various fields in which user can enter data.
I have a button.
I want to pass values entered by user on the GUI, and on the button click, I want to pass those values to another page where i can use them.

**Note:** No form/No onSubmit/No form action, it is just a page redirect to another page using a button.

Comment: _"it is just a page redirect to another page using a button"_ ...with values passed along? That's _exactly_ what a form is for. Why don't you want a form?

Comment: Could you be a little more clear? You have 'various fields' but 'no form'? is this a confirmation page of sorts for review of the data that was submitted?

Comment: Actually i have a form with various fields, that also has onsubmit, and data is saved in DB on pressing that button but i also want another button on the same page. that exports the data to another page. So i was using a page redirect for that purpose

Comment: You can have multiple submit buttons in a form and perform different processing based on which one was selected? That seems a better solution, but if you must do it without then you'll need JavaScript: either using window.location, or - if you're using jQuery/similar - using .load(url,data) might simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on some markup:

```
<div id="x">Some data</div>
<div id="y">Some more data</div>
```

jQuery script to retrieve the data you want:

```
$("my button/link/whatever").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        x: $("#x").text(),
        y: $("#y").text()
    };
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "the page to send data to",
        type: "post",
        data: data
    });
    req.done(function(response) {
        // Do something here once the request is complete
    });
});
```

Or use a second form.